# jQuery on 'click' not triggering after change to a bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-on

## situation

I am using bootstrap to render a table based on values in an array of objects. I have a select which has a jQuery on ('change') method attached so that when an item from the list is selected, a new table is rendered based on the selected value.

the table uses bootstrap collapse to show/hide rows from the table when the top row is clicked.  the last item in the row has a glyphicon arrow which shows the row can be folded/unfolded as the picture below shows

[collapse with glyphicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpUIl.png)

I am using the below jQuery to toggle the icon

```
$('#tog').on('click', function() {
  console.log("tog clicked");
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-up glyphicon-arrow-down');
});
```

so far I have this all working as shown with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vgfb74u0/

## Problem

the issue I am facing is that when a new table is rendered based on the selected item the jQuery that changes the glyphic does not trigger so when the table unfolds the icon remains the same.

I have put in some console.log at the start of the method and I never see it firing. so to my newbie eyes the click event is never triggered.

I'm surprised that i've managed to get this far and at a loss to what the issue might be so any help, pointers or advise is most welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to manually bind events to any dynamically created element, or let jQuery do that for you.

Changing

```
$('#tog').on('click', function() {});
```

To

```
$('html').on('click', '#tog', function() {});
```

Will tell JavaScript to delegate the event to any `#tog` that's created inside the `<html>` element.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was struggling unable to understand why it was not triggering. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the event handler is lost when the table is re-rendered.
The fix is to attach the handler in a different way: `$('.table').on('click', '#tog', function() {...}`

[See the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgfb74u0/1/)